# Overlapping flash in Internet explorer

Tags: html, flash, internet-explorer, overlay

I am having issues using flash with Internet Explorer browser. I have a web application which opens a book in a flash pdf viewer. This pdf can have several links pointing to some flash games, animations, etc that are opnened in a new html popup above.

The thing is that the external resource opens correctly, but when I close it, the viewer resets and goes blank, as if the instance of flash for it has terminated. I think it is because the flash viewer was hidden during the playback of the external animation and it was discarded by hte browser.

It only happens on IE.

Does anyone know some kind of workaround for this?